# MySql query on multiple tables with group by

Tags: mysql

I have 4 tables as described below and I am trying the fetch all lots in bids table while I am getting all the records in auction lots table.

The query that I tried is also given below along with the db structure that is being used.

```
Auctions (id, name)

id | name
-----------
1 | auction1
2 | auction2


Auction_lots (id, name, auction_id)

id | name | auction_id
---------------------------------
1 | lot1 | 2
2 | lot2 | 2
3 | lot3 | 2
4 | lot4 | 2
5 | lot5 | 2


Bids (id, user_id, auction_id, lot_id)

id | user_id | auction_id | lot_id
--------------------------------------------
1 |   1    |    2      |  5
2 |   1    |    2      |  3
3 |   1    |    2      |  1
4 |   1    |    2      |  2


Users(id, name)

id | name
-----------
1 | user1
2 | user2
```

I need all auction_lots where user placed bids with auction name, lot name and user details

I tried

```
    select PB.*, U.*, A.name as auc_name, AL.name as lot_name
    from auctions as A INNER JOIN
        auction_lots as AL
        ON A.id = AL.auction_id RIGHT JOIN
        phone_bids as PB
        ON AL.auction_id = PB.auction_id INNER JOIN
        users as U
        ON PB.user_id = U.id
    WHERE U.id =".$user_id."
    GROUP BY lot_name
```

I just need lot in bids table while getting  all lots

Comment: why you add that right join ? and without any aggregate function you have added a group by so i removed those

Answer (score 0, accepted):

REMOVE RIGHT JOIN AND GROUP BY YOU WILL GET WHAT YOU WANT

```
select 
        PB.*, U.*, A.name as auc_name, AL.name as lot_name

    from
        auctions as A

    INNER JOIN
        auction_lots as AL
        ON
        A.id = AL.auction_id

   INNER JOIN
        phone_bids as PB
        ON
        AL.auction_id = PB.auction_id

    INNER JOIN
        users as U
        ON
        PB.user_id =U.id
    WHERE
        U.id =".$user_id."
```

Comment: It didn't work. I tried following and it worked fine... but don't know if its a correct way of doing it
---------------------------------------------------------------------
 "select 
  PB.*, U.*, A.name as auc_name, AL.name as lot_name

 from
  phone_bids as PB

 LEFT JOIN
  auctions as A
  ON
  PB.auction_id = A.id
 LEFT JOIN
  auction_lots as AL
  ON
  PB.lot_id = AL.id
 LEFT JOIN
  users as U
  ON
  PB.user_id =U.id

 WHERE
  U.id =".$user_id."

Comment: when your taking left join if you start with phon_bids and if you left join other tables to it you will get all records in phon_bids and only the related mapping records from other tables but in above example phon bids is mapping table and it cant have entries which are not matching with other tables

Comment: It wasn't the error... it was just showing all records from tables .... and yes... I only wanted matching records of the bids table ... still I will check it thoroughly on the website and if any problem will revert back... anyway ... thanks for your response

Comment: my question is is it possibale to have entry on bids table without related entry on user /action or lots?

Comment: Bids table will have entries only if related entry is there in the related table ... But I understand your point and have modified by query as     .............................."select PB.*, U.*, A.name as auc_name, AL.name as lot_name from phone_bids as PB INNER JOIN auctions as A ON PB.auction_id = A.id INNER JOIN auction_lots as AL ON PB.lot_id = AL.id INNER JOIN users as U ON PB.user_id =U.id WHERE U.id =".$user_id."

Comment: I would love to .... only thing is that we will have to start with bids table in the query and not with auctions table ... but you raised a good logical point that if bids table have direct entries or not ... which made me to adjust the query .. though that have no effect in this case... still point you raised was logical so I accept it ... many - 2 thanks